# Bad Request (Invalid Hostname) on working server, database problem

Tags: plugins, admin, database, mysql, wp-config

I have a local server up using EasyPHP. I know its working because I have a default wordpress install running and up on my brower. I have a full site which I also know I have working because when I set up an empty database and then did the wordpress install the theme was working perfectly but without the content. I have a backup of the actual database this site used and when I create a database, and import the data using PHPMyAdmin and connect it in the wp-config.php file I am getting:

Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated the database with phpmyadmin to reflect the correct URL?

Comment: What home url (and wordpress url) is in the wp_options table? Update: Ah, @GhostToast was faster. :)

Comment: Do you mean siteurl inside wp_options? I did try to change that and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I wrote a little function to generate the necessary phpmyadmin SQL script for moving from one domain to another. Put *before* url in one end, and *after* url in other. Then select it, copy it, paste it in the SQL box in phpmyadmin and presto-changeo. Backup database first though...can't be held accountable :) http://tools.morningstarmediagroup.com/find-replace/

Comment: THis is a great tool GhostToast! worked like a charm. I had to select the database first before the rest of your sql worked. Thanks!

Comment: Well in that case I'm submitting an answer!

Comment: So the website is working now but all of the links in the menu and on the site arent working. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Permalinks.   `.htaccess` needs to be rebuilt (and this will do that for you just by visiting that page) everytime something major like a URL change occurs.

Comment: I have a Bad Request after I moved a WP site from a domain to another. I've used @GhostToast script and update the DB but nothing changes. Also I've tried to rebuild the .htaccess file but the problem remains. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have updated your database to reflect the correct URL. You can do this in phpmyadmin with a bit of SQL. Good article about it here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database